In same project, pytorch can use cuda but onnxruntime infer with cuda raise err "CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED"
Here is my code:
import os.path

import onnxruntime
import numpy as np
import cv2
from onnxruntime import SessionOptions

# Load the ONNX model
d = os.path.abspath(f"{__file__}/..")

# os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "2"
# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH
home = os.environ.get("HOME")

onnx_model_path = f'{d}/RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime_6B.onnx'
# Specify CUDA execution provider when creating the session
providers = [
    ('CUDAExecutionProvider', {
        # 'gpu_mem_limit': 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
    })
]
sess_opt = SessionOptions()
# set max cpu cores n
# sess_opt.intra_op_num_threads = 2
ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_model_path, sess_opt, providers=providers)

# ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_model_path, providers=[cudaP, 'AzureExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider'])  # in my old deivce with 18.04, cannot install libonnxruntime_providers_cuda, so cannot use cuda
# ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_model_path, providers=["CUDAExecutionProvider"])

# Load and preprocess input image
# input_image_path = f"{d}/small.jpg"
input_image_path = f"{d}/big.jpg"
# input_image_path = f"{d}/big.jpg"
input_image = cv2.imread(input_image_path)
input_image = cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Convert BGR to RGB
input_image = input_image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0  # Normalize to [0, 1]
input_image = np.transpose(input_image, (2, 0, 1))  # Change the shape from HWC to CHW
input_image = np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension

# Perform inference
ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: input_image}
ort_outs = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)

# Post-process the output
output_image = ort_outs[0][0]  # Assuming only one output
output_image = np.transpose(output_image, (1, 2, 0))  # Change the shape from CHW to HWC
output_image = (output_image * 255).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert back to uint8 and clip values

# Display or save the output image
out = f"{d}/out.jpg"  # Adjust output path as needed
cv2.imwrite(out, cv2.cvtColor(output_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
print(f"out {out}")

And the full error I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 419, in __init__
    self._create_inference_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
  File "/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 463, in _create_inference_session
    sess.initialize_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.RuntimeException: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 6 : RUNTIME_EXCEPTION : Exception during initialization: /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/providers/cuda/cuda_call.cc:121 std::conditional_t<THRW, void, onnxruntime::common::Status> onnxruntime::CudaCall(ERRTYPE, const char*, const char*, ERRTYPE, const char*, const char*, int) [with ERRTYPE = cudnnStatus_t; bool THRW = true; std::conditional_t<THRW, void, onnxruntime::common::Status> = void] /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/providers/cuda/cuda_call.cc:114 std::conditional_t<THRW, void, onnxruntime::common::Status> onnxruntime::CudaCall(ERRTYPE, const char*, const char*, ERRTYPE, const char*, const char*, int) [with ERRTYPE = cudnnStatus_t; bool THRW = true; std::conditional_t<THRW, void, onnxruntime::common::Status> = void] CUDNN failure 1: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED ; GPU=0 ; hostname=roroco ; file=/onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/providers/cuda/cuda_execution_provider.cc ; line=172 ; expr=cudnnCreate(&cudnn_handle_); 

In the same project, torch can use CUDA but ONNX Runtime cannot. I think they use same CUDA and cuDNN. How to make the ONNX Runtime inference code work?
In both cases, I use the following CUDA and cuDNN versions:
> torch.version.cuda
11.8

> torch.backends.cudnn.version()
8700

